# How do I loop through files in a directory given from the command line?

Tags: bash

I am trying to build a script from the command line. But everytime I run, my echo command only prints the directory name and not the files inside the directory.

```
for EachFile in $1:
do
  #Do stuff
  echo "Filename is $EachFile"

done
```

Comment: `for var in ...` iterates over the *list of "words"* following `in`, not over files in a directory. To iterate over the files in a directory, you need to convert the list of files in that directory into a list of words, and a shell wildcard expression (like `"$dir"/*`) is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Colon has no special meaning in paths. Use a glob:

```
for file in "$1"/* ; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```